# AOP - JoinPoint.getTarget().getClass()のCASTを行いたい

Tags: java, spring

現在下記のような実装になっており、Objectクラスに、joinPointから取得したクラスを代入しております。
そして、変数:targetを TEST1クラス にcastしたいのですが方法が分かりません。
分かる方がいましたらご教授お願い致します。

```
@Before("execution～")
public void before(JoinPoint joinPoint) throws Exception {
   Object target = joinPoint.getTarget().getClass();
}
```

因みに、下記のcast方法はエラーとなっておりました。

```html
1.
Object target = joinPoint.getTarget().getClass();
TEST1 test1 = (TEST1)target;

2.
Object obj = new Test1();
Test1 test1 = joinPoint.getTarget().getClass().cast(obj);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

下記でインスタンスを生成することが出来ます。

```html
Class target = joinPoint.getTarget().getClass();
Constructor<?> cunstructor = target.getConstructors()[0];
TEST1 test1 = (TEST1)cunstructor.newInstance();
```